# Spring Boot: Dependency Injection Issue - GameService not Initialized in CustomHandShakeInterceptor

Tags: dependency-injection, autowired, interceptor, spring-websocket

I'm trying to control Websocket connection. So, I implemented a customHandShakeInterceptor.
For some reason it is not creating instance of my service.

```
@Component
public class CustomHandShakeInterceptor extends HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor {
      @Autowired private GameService gameService;

      @Override
      public boolean beforeHandshake(
              ServerHttpRequest request,
              @NonNull ServerHttpResponse response,
              @NonNull WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
              @NonNull Map<String, Object> attributes
      ) throws Exception {
            String query = request.getURI().getQuery();
            if(query != null && query.contains("game_id"))  {
                  String game = query.substring(query.indexOf("game_id=") + 8);
                  gameService.getGame(game);
                  if(gameService.getGame(game) == null) {
                        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

                        String jsonResponse = "{\"error\": \"Game not found\"}";
                        response.getBody().write(jsonResponse.getBytes());
                        return false;
                  }
            }
            return super.beforeHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, attributes);
      }
}
```

I'm getting error when I try connecting to websocket.

`Cannot invoke "projects.web.tictactoe.service.GameService.getGame(String)" because "this.gameService" is null`

I tried adding GameService class manually `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = GameService.class)`
Also tried moving CustomHandShakeInterceptor class to other packages but the result is same.

I don't want to create a new instance of GameService becaue it has data of all ongoing games.

I'm looking to understand why it is not being handled by spring and I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I figured it. I was creating a new instance of CustomHandShakeInterceptor in WebSocketConfig, I  autowired CustomHandShakeInterceptor and the code works fine.